# can't right click paste in chrome dev tool

Tags: html, copy-paste, right-click, chromebook

Does anyone know why I can't right click paste in chrome dev tool?

When editing as html I can paste in text using ctrl-v but the right click menu doesn't show paste as an option. ???

This is on a Chromebook.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and then on again?

Answer (score 0):

When you are editing the html, select the whole text or line and then push the right click and you will be able to paste.